# Optimizing a sql query used for searching articles

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a query I am using to search a database. The query gets build in code and the terms are  parameterized so everything is run nice and safe. I say that because the terms can't come from a table as they are generated based on user input from a search field.

Everything works like it should, I'm just wondering if there is a better/faster way to perform the search.

```
SELECT
  sum(score * multiplier) score,
  a.id,
  a.title
FROM
(
  SELECT 3 score, 'a railway employee' term UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 score, 'railway employee' term UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 score, 'a railway' term UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 score, 'employee' term UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 score, 'railway' term UNION ALL
  SELECT 0 score, 'a' term
) terms
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT 'title' TYPE, 1 multiplier
  UNION ALL SELECT 'summary', 1.1
  UNION ALL SELECT 'detail', 1.5
) X
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT id, 'title' TYPE, title SEARCH FROM article
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, 'summary' TYPE, summary SEARCH FROM article WHERE summary <> ''
  UNION ALL
  SELECT artId, 'detail' TYPE, txt SEARCH FROM articleSections
) s ON s.TYPE = x.TYPE AND SEARCH LIKE concat('%', terms.term, '%')
INNER JOIN article a ON a.id = s.id
GROUP BY id, title
ORDER BY score DESC;
;
```

A functional simple demo is on [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57bbc/48).

Comment: Looks like you're trying to emulate full-text searching using `LIKE`. Why not use the real thing? `LIKE` queries can't use an index if the pattern begins with `%`.

Comment: Have you considered using Sphinx, Solr or Elasticsearch instead? This will always perform horrible like this.

Comment: @Barmar - How would I go about altering this query to use full-text searching and get the same score for each title in the results?

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks good enough for me. However, you can get a little bit better execution plan if you are willing to trade readability for performance by repeating join condition for each part of your `UNION` :

```
....
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT id, 'title' TYPE, title SEARCH FROM article
   where title like '%a railway employee%' or 
  title like '%railway employee%' 
  or title like '%a railway%'
  or title like '%employee%'
  or title like '%railway%'
  or title like '%a%'
  UNION ALL ....
```