# Converting a MySQL LIKE query into a Full-Text query

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

OK, so I have a nice little query that returns scored results. The query is currently `LIKE` based and I would like to convert it over to a full-text query as [everyone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254393/optimizing-a-sql-query-used-for-searching-articles?noredirect=1#comment25006957_17254393) [keeps](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27649/im-looking-for-suggestions-and-comments-on-my-simple-search-algorithm?noredirect=1#comment43154_27649) telling me to. I would like to get the same result order if not the same scores. The only way I've been able to get anything close is by unrolling my cross join...

- I want to be able to set the scores for specific word combinations
- I want to be able to set the weight based on where the term is found
- I dont want a to search based on a [Power Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of the words in the search. That is if the user enters "a railway employee" I don't want to search for "a employee" at any point. I am trying to search for only consecutive groupings of terms from the query.

How can I make my original query full-text based and still keep it relatively small and organized?

You can see both queries on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab7ce/52).

**original query** - Nice and small, the scores and search terms are all in once place

```
SELECT
  sum(score * multiplier) score,
  a.id,
  a.title
FROM
(
  SELECT 3 score, 'a railway employee' term UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 score, 'railway employee' term UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 score, 'a railway' term UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 score, 'employee' term UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 score, 'railway' term UNION ALL
  SELECT 0 score, 'a' term
) terms
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT 'T' TYPE, 1 multiplier
  UNION ALL SELECT 'S', 1.1
  UNION ALL SELECT 'C', 1.5
) x
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT id, 'T' TYPE, title SEARCH FROM articles
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, 'S' TYPE, summary SEARCH FROM articles WHERE summary <> ''
  UNION ALL
  SELECT artId, 'C' TYPE, content SEARCH FROM articleSections
) s ON s.TYPE = x.TYPE AND SEARCH LIKE concat('%', terms.term, '%')
INNER JOIN articles a ON a.id = s.id
WHERE score > 0
GROUP BY id, title
ORDER BY score DESC, title;
;
```

**Full-Text** - Messy and big, the scores and search terms are all over the place

```
SELECT
  sum(score * multiplier) score,
  id,
  title
FROM
(
SELECT
  3 score,
  1 multiplier,
  'T' AS loc,
  id,
  title
FROM articles
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('"a railway employee"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  2 score,
  1 multiplier,
  'T' AS loc,
  id,
  title
FROM articles
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('"railway employee"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  2 score,
  1 multiplier,
  'T' AS loc,
  id,
  title
FROM articles
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('"a railway"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  1 score,
  1 multiplier,
  'T' AS loc,
  id,
  title
FROM articles
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('railway' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  1 score,
  1 multiplier,
  'T' AS loc,
  id,
  title
FROM articles
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('employee' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
UNION ALL


SELECT
  3 score,
  1 multiplier,
  'S' AS loc,
  id,
  title
FROM articles
WHERE MATCH(summary) AGAINST ('"a railway employee"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  2 score,
  1.1 multiplier,
  'S' AS loc,
  id,
  title
FROM articles
WHERE MATCH(summary) AGAINST ('"railway employee"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  2 score,
  1.1 multiplier,
  'S' AS loc,
  id,
  title
FROM articles
WHERE MATCH(summary) AGAINST ('"a railway"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  1 score,
  1.1 multiplier,
  'S' AS loc,
  id,
  title
FROM articles
WHERE MATCH(summary) AGAINST ('railway' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  1 score,
  1.1 multiplier,
  'S' AS loc,
  id,
  title
FROM articles
WHERE MATCH(summary) AGAINST ('employee' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
UNION ALL


SELECT
  3 score,
  1.5 multiplier,
  'C' AS loc,
  id,
  title
FROM articleSections
INNER JOIN articles a ON a.id = artId
WHERE MATCH(content) AGAINST ('"a railway employee"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  2 score,
  1.5 multiplier,
  'C' AS loc,
  id,
  title
FROM articleSections
INNER JOIN articles a ON a.id = artId
WHERE MATCH(content) AGAINST ('"railway employee"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  2 score,
  1.5 multiplier,
  'C' AS loc,
  id,
  title
FROM articleSections
INNER JOIN articles a ON a.id = artId
WHERE MATCH(content) AGAINST ('"a railway"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  1 score,
  1.5 multiplier,
  'C' AS loc,
  id,
  title
FROM articleSections
INNER JOIN articles a ON a.id = artId
WHERE MATCH(content) AGAINST ('railway' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  1 score,
  1.5 multiplier,
  'C' AS loc,
  id,
  title
FROM articleSections
INNER JOIN articles a ON a.id = artId
WHERE MATCH(content) AGAINST ('employee' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

) t
WHERE score > 0
GROUP BY id, title
ORDER BY score DESC, title;
;
```

Comment: You've got a faulty set of requirement. These "requirements" you listed are artificial and limits the kinds of solutions you can do. Requirements should constrain solutions, not specify them. Please rethink of what you want from the search and edit.

Comment: @LieRyan - I want to be able to determine how and why a title is in the result... to do that I want to determine how things are scored and what things are scored... If I didn't care about what results I got back I would just but a WHERE MATCH at the end of a simple select and be done with it.

Comment: @Justin808 . . . Given your scoring needs, you may not want to use full text search at all.  Or, you might want to use full text search to find rows that contain you keywords, and then use `like` and `join` to add up the scores.

Comment: That's still not a real requirement. Why do you want to specify this exact sorting order? Is there any real reason why this exact sorting algorithm is the only viable solution compared to all other the alternatives, is there any reason other than just it's the way it was done in a previous implementation, why do you need this exact sorting order?

Comment: Basically, if you need this very scoring algorithm, then you will not gain much from using a full-text search. However, full text searches in [natural language](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) already compute a matching score, although computed with a different set of rules.

Comment: @YaK - When I remove "IN BOOLEAN MODE" I get no results so its not that great, cant really mess with it to see how it works. When I asked I was told to use "IN BOOLEAN MODE" and I got no score.

Comment: @LieRyan - I don't necessarily need this sorting order but I would like to mess with the scores and weights. I don't really like black boxes. I would like to tweak how things work.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Apparently, you have very specific scoring needs that are met neither by the natural language mode of search nor the boolean mode of search.  I wonder if there is some hidden mechanism in MySQL that will give you the list of keyword matches to a search, which you can then use for scoring.  I don't know of any.

If you have a large corpus and relatively rare words (meaning that the words you are looking for are in relatively few documents), then you can use the boolean mode to whittle down the search space.  Such a query would look something like:

```
select t.id, sum(terms.score * wherefactor.factor)
from (select t.*
      . . .
      where MATCH(title, summary, content) AGAINST ('railway employee' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
     ) t left outer join
     (SELECT 3 score, 'a railway employee' term UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 score, 'railway employee' term UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 score, 'a railway' term UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 score, 'employee' term UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 score, 'railway' term UNION ALL
      SELECT 0 score, 'a' term
    ) terms cross join
    (SELECT 'T' as which, 1.0 as factor UNION ALL
     SELECT 'S', 1.1 UNION ALL
     SELECT 'C', 1.5
    ) wherefactor
    on (case when wherefacctor.which = 'T' then title 
             when wherefactor.which = 'S' then subject
             when wherefactor.which = 'C' then content
        end) like concat('%', term, '%')
group by t.id;
```

This should give you the performance of the full text search along with the specifics of your scoring algorithm.

Another possibility, if you have a known lexicon, is to build a document-term table.  Such a table would have one row for each document and each term in the document that you care about (this is called a "lexicon").  With such a data structure, you would be free to implement any score mechanism of your choosing.